# sqlite3 linking errors on mac osx

Tags: xcode, sqlite

While porting a program from windows to mac, I am building a C/C++ library in xcode. 
The library uses sqlite3 c api. previously in windows the sqlite3 source code was compiled as part of the library.

I have to compile my library to be compatible with 32 and 64 bit platforms both and need to support mac osx 10.5 onwards till 10.8

On mac there seems to be sqlite3 built in, so I guess I do not need to compile sqlite3 code in the project and rather refer to the library already on the platform

the library compiles but gives linking error for sqlite3 function calls,

I was able to find sqlite3.dylib on mac which is a dynamic library.

In windows we'd use a loadlibrary() function call to use dlls. So what confuses me is whether I have to change my code to perhaps make a call similar to loadlibrary() for mac and then use it ? I am not sure.. I am new to mac.

I was expecting a static library of sqlite3 on mac, the one I found is dylib,  if I can link sqlite3 statically it would probably be best because I would not need to change much of code.

How do I link to it to platform available sqlite3 library in my xcode project ?  or do I need to compile the sqlite3 code as part of my project and ignore the dylib on the platform ?

Any help please ?

Comment: When you say "the library compiles but gives linking error for sqlite3 function calls" you mean the final binary that *uses* the library give the linker errors, given the library is static (and therefore linking is not involved when building the library)?

Comment: No, I meant when I build the library xcode gives me linking errors for sqlite3 calls (there are no compile time errors) I have not used the library in anyother binary yet because I can not even build it. The library I am building is of type dylib , in xcode 4.3 I selected frameworks & library -> C/C++ linrary to create this library project

Comment: OK, sounds like you just need to link in the `sqlite3` library, which can be set in the project build settings.

Comment: Any directions for that ? so when I ship this library on any other platform will it automatically pick the sqlite3 there ? 32/64 bit both ?

Comment: It's covered in the Xcode guide (which is included in Xcode) and yes - it will use the system's `sqlite3` dynamic library at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifndef WIN32
typedef void* HANDLE
inline HANDLE LoadLibrary(char path[])
{
    return (HANDLE) dlopen(path, RTLD_NOW);
}
inline void FreeLibrary(HANDLE handle)
{
    dlclose((void*) handle);
}
#endif
```

// put the above function in a header, then you can continue to use LoadLibrary syntax